# Change google app engine name

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i cloned a working google app engine repo into my local env and got it to work.
Later i decided i wanted to deploy to my own GAE app so i changed the name in app.yaml to the one in my newly created app.

But then when launching it with the GoogleAppEngineLauncher i got this error:

```
BadRequestError: app "dev~bandtasticnews" cannot access app "dev~noticiashacker"'s data
```

The original name is noticiashacker and the new one is bandtasticnews, the cloned worked alright online but the dev is broken, i have to change the name on app.yaml to the original if i want it to launch locally and return it before deploying.

There are no more lines on my code referencing the original name, i don't know why is it trying to retrieve it.

UPDATE
Here is the stack trace shown in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher logs

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8000 --clear_datastore=yes
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2013-04-24 00:45:10,683 devappserver2.py:498] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-04-24 00:45:10,690 api_server.py:328] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-04-24 00:45:10,693 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:50495
INFO     2013-04-24 00:45:10,700 dispatcher.py:150] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-04-24 00:45:10,706 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/mtime_file_watcher.py:82: UserWarning: There are too many files in your application for changes in all of them to be monitored. You may have to restart the development server to see some changes to your files.
  'There are too many files in your application for '
ERROR    2013-04-24 00:45:17,489 webapp2.py:1528] app "dev~bandtasticnews" cannot access app "dev~noticiashacker"'s data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/grillermo/c/BandtasticNews/Noticias-HAcker/handlers/MainHandler.py", line 85, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/main.html', locals()))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 92, in render
    return t.render(Context(template_dict))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 172, in wrap_render
    return orig_render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 125, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 257, in render
    return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 842, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 551, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 694, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 729, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/Users/grillermo/c/BandtasticNews/Noticias-HAcker/models.py", line 73, in sum_votes
    self.put()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1070, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 579, in Put
    return PutAsync(entities, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1569, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1224, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: app "dev~bandtasticnews" cannot access app "dev~noticiashacker"'s data
INFO     2013-04-24 00:45:17,532 recording.py:673] Saved; key: __appstats__:017200, part: 157 bytes, full: 69853 bytes, overhead: 0.003 + 0.031; link: http://localhost:8080/_ah/stats/details?time=1366764317201
ERROR    2013-04-24 00:45:17,538 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/grillermo/c/BandtasticNews/Noticias-HAcker/main.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/grillermo/c/BandtasticNews/Noticias-HAcker/main.py", line 86, in main
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 118, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    for data in result:
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 1284, in appstats_wsgi_wrapper
    result = app(environ, appstats_start_response)
  File "/Users/grillermo/c/BandtasticNews/Noticias-HAcker/gaesessions/__init__.py", line 451, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, my_start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/grillermo/c/BandtasticNews/Noticias-HAcker/handlers/MainHandler.py", line 85, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/main.html', locals()))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 92, in render
    return t.render(Context(template_dict))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 172, in wrap_render
    return orig_render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 125, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 257, in render
    return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 794, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 807, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 842, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 551, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 694, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 729, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/Users/grillermo/c/BandtasticNews/Noticias-HAcker/models.py", line 73, in sum_votes
    self.put()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1070, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 579, in Put
    return PutAsync(entities, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1569, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1224, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: app "dev~bandtasticnews" cannot access app "dev~noticiashacker"'s data
```

UPDATE
Tried it on a different computer and it was the same thing, but this time i tried to run the app without ever having the name noticiashacker on it.

UPDATE
The app.yaml

```
application: bandtasticnews
version: 5
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"

builtins:
- appstats: on
- remote_api: on

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
- url: /reports/.*
  script: reports.py
  login: admin
- url: /tasks/send_top_to_twitter
  script: crons.py
  login: admin
- url: /tasks/send_to_killmetrics
  script: crons.py
  login: admin
- url: /tasks/update_top_karma
  script: crons.py
  login: admin
- url: /tasks/cleanup_sessions
  script: crons.py
  login: admin
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico   
- url: /robots.txt             
  static_files: static/robots.txt 
  upload: static/robots.txt    
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.py
  login: admin
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Comment: I have no idea what launcher is (Don't want to know) Is this a Python app with an app.yaml file? Or is it Java?

Comment: Python App, but never mind the launcher with the dev_appserver.py i get the same error.

Comment: What does your app.yaml look like?

Comment: Added it to the question, thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this, first download your app to a new directory

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

Create a new app.yaml with the app id you want to use (don't copy it but create it new)
then run dev_appserver ./

good luck

Comment: It was the main folder, it should have the same name as the one in the app.yaml. Thanks, yours is the bounty.

Comment: Wow thanks, it was a bit of a lucky guess though, glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

You have data from the old appid in the dev datastore.

You need to clear you local datastore with --clear_datastore  when you start the dev server.  Not sure how you do that in the Launcher (never use it)

Comment: Tried that already with the dev_appserver.py and with the GoogleAppEngineLauncher using a checkbox on the UI. The problem persists i think i got to delete some folder on my mac.

Comment: Unsuccesfully tried to remove the googleappenginelauncher and reinstalling it.

Comment: I found the datastore.db file deleted it and the error persists.

Comment: Can you find dev_appserver.datastore anywhere?

Comment: just specify a new datastore with --datastore_path

Comment: Ok i tried --datastore_path=dev~bandtasticnews from the dev_appserver.py and the GAELauncher and the error persists, exactly the same error.

Comment: @dragonx there is only a datastore.db

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in to admin console,

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

while keeping the original name, you can see some data in datastore viewer, clear it off (for all types of entities), stop the dev-server and change the name to new one, and start again. It should work.

The problem is with namespaces, the way google separates data between multiple applications. Some of your data is persisted with old namespace which is not getting deleted.

Comment: you can alternatively try deleting folder appengine-generated, it contains a file named local_db.bin (which actually stores your data), and xml which tells how to create indexes, and indexes created on your data.
in simple case deleting or renaming local_db.bin should suffice

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply deleting the cookie solves the problem. I found this solution after that I observed that Chrome incognito mode had no problem with it.